# How can I write junit for multi level service classes in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

Suppose I have one controller and multiple services in this.

```
Class Controller1{
     private ServiceA servicea;
}

Class ServiceA {
     private ServiceB serviceb;
}

Class ServiceB {
     private ServiceC servicec;
     private Utility utility;
}

Class ServiceC {
     private Dao dao;
}
```

In the bouve example if I want to write unit test for ServiceA so I have to Mock ServiceB.

First question: Testing only one service class does not make much sence for me, because these are all related services and work together.

Can I inject ServiceB as well as ServiceC to ServiceB instead of mocking them?

Basically I don't want to any serivces class. I want to mock only Dao layers.

But the problem is Dao is at very of the flow.

How can I solve this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

My code example

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class ServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    ServiceA servicea;
    
    @Mock
    ServiceB serviceb;
    @Mock
    ServiceC servicec;

    
    @Test
    public void testFeatureOne() 
    {
      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Testing only one service class does not make much sence for me,
> because these are all related services and work together.

Do you want to do unit tests or integration tests? If you want unit tests then you should test each service separately. Using Mockito you can both define responses of mocked services and verify that the service under test actually interacts with underlying mocked services.

If you actually want to do an integration tests of all services at once, there's no problem with that as well. I believe you could do something like so, by hand:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class ServiceTest {

  
    ServiceA servicea;
    ServiceB serviceb;
    ServiceC servicec;

    @Mock
    Dao dao;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        servicec = new ServiceC(dao);
        serviceb = new ServiceB(servicec, new Utility());
        servicea = new ServiceA(serviceb);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testFeatureOne() 
    {
      
    }
}
```

I could be wrong but I'm guessing you could do the same with `@Autowire` annotation on all 3 services and `@InjectMock` on `servicec` (haven't tried it myself, just a guess).

Comment: No @InjectMock doesn't work like that. Here services classes are nested. Actually we have little complex application and there are multiple services talk each other to derive a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but you dont want to unittest but integration test.

[Marting Fowler - Test Pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html)